# Goole OCR not detecting tables with their structure

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I followed a tutorial and tried using Google OCR to convert image into text, I have a table and it is of the form "`Text value value value`", but Google OCR is reading it as

```
Text

Value

Value

Value
```

Is there a way to read it as it is? Without losing the text to value relation?

Answer (score 2):

Even i was facing the same problem.After pretty much research i found out that there are something called table OCR's and vision api's TEXT_DETECTION and DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION are not table ocr's meaning they are not suitable for tabular data reproduction u need a lot of opencv image preprocessing to be done.Instead u can make use of table OCR API'(FREE) on the internet ,

- [FREE Table Ocr API](https://ocr.space/tablerecognition)
- [github opensource Table OCR's developed on TESSERACT](https://github.com/cseas/ocr-table)

they make sure that your text-value relation isn't broken
they OCR'ed output of
[nutrifact data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UukFJ.jpg)

would be

`Nutrition fact
blah blah boo
Totalfat 0g 0%//in the same line
Sodium 0mg  0%//in the same line
.........   ..`

hence u can keep "\t " as delimeter and reproduce the table

hope my  answer would b helpful:)